# Restrict users to specific ssh

Tags: debian, ssh, users

So I have this issue at the moment, where everyone could theoretically log in into my Debian server as sudo if they had the password. Can I somehow restrict a user/group to a specific ssh-key so that only that machine with the specific ssh-key can log in as sudo?

To visualize:

- The sudo group, let's call it wheel, should only be loginable with a specific ssh.
- Every other group should be loginable via ssh or password.

Comment: *log in into my Debian server as sudo if they had the password* - this doesn't make sense, this is not how authentication works unless you've done something specific to the `sudo` configuration.

Comment: You don't "_log in [...] as sudo_". You login with a user account, which may or may not have rights to use `sudo` - depending on how you've configured the utility. Please can you [provide an example or two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/705000/edit) of what you mean because it's far from clear at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can disable password authentication for specific users and groups. E.g., to prevent the wheel group from authenticating via passwords you can put:

```
Match Group wheel
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

In your `sshd_config` config (`typically at /etc/ssh/sshd_config`).

[More details here](https://ostechnix.com/disable-ssh-password-authentication-for-specific-user-or-group/).

Restart sshd afterwards.